# Autolayout vertical spacing of group of textlabels when one is empty

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a group of text labels that are vertically spaced to each other **15 pixels**.
[image]

The problem is that when one of the labels is empty, then there is extra space between the other two labels above and below the empty one (30 pixels).

I know that one solution would be to constraint all the text labels to the top and to the labels above and then I can just delete it and everything should look aligned but the problem is that I reuse the view and sometimes all the labels have text and sometimes some are empty. So if I delete the label, I would have to recreate it and readjust the constraints manually.

**Is there a way to delete the extra vertical spacing when one of the labels is empty without deleting it?**

**Edit 1:** The labels don't have any **Height** constraint so the empty one will be 0 pixels high

**Edit 2:** I need to support iOS7+

Comment: Don't set `Height` constraint to any label, let them adjust height according to text.

Comment: I'm not sure if labels' height auto-shrinks to zero when text is empty. But perhaps setting font size to zero would do the trick?

Comment: I don't set the **Height** constraint to any of the labels. The empty one will have **0** height but there will be 15 pixels above and 15 pixels below. I want to get rid of one of those 15 pixels margin so all the labels have the same separation.

Comment: Take the outlets of all your vertical space constraints.If text is empty set vertical space constraint from top label to current label make it zero

Comment: The best approach would depend on your deployment target, there're [shortcuts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html) if you can support only the latest iOS versions, otherwise I'm afraid you'll have to modify the constraints manually.

Comment: Why don't you try by adding only one label and create a formatted string from inputs and set it to the label. (Just to tell another approach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible options:

- do not use multiple labels, but a single one, possibly using an attributed string if you need different formatting for the different parts
- add an outlet to each of your constraints, and adjust the constant based on the label having text or not

There are quite a few others, including the use of table views, stack views (iOS 9+), and probably more...

Comment: I think I will add an outlet for each constraint and modify them accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[image]If you are ok with supporting iOS 9 and above then you can use stack view and set the constraints for the labels within the stack view. But instead of emptying the label you should hide the label. When the label is hidden the stack view automatically brings up all the labels below it. You should get the desired behaviour using this method.

Comment: If you want to support older OS then you have to maintain an array of labels and their strings and have to manipulate the array so that you move all the non-empty strings up the array and update the labels array accordingly and remove the last empty labels. You could use IBCollection to group the labels into a single outlet

Answer (score 0):

My rule of thumb is if layouts get overly complicated to do in Interface Builder, then it's better to just write code to do it. In this case I'm not even sure it's possible to define in IB. But even if it was, I'd do it in code. It's not a complicated layout, it will be more reusable, it will be cleaner in code.

A few options:

A - You could modify constraints in viewWillLayoutSubviews - it's kinda messy to hold on to so many top constraints. Somewhat less messy if you add them all to an outlet collection (array of outlets, basically).

B - You could manually adjust frames in viewDidLayoutSubviews - although it then begs the question, why even use AutoLayout at all if you're doing almost all the work manually anyway.

C - Use SnapKit and generate those constraints in viewDidLoad and / or update them whenever the text changes. I highly recommend SnapKit. Think of it as a sane way of programmatically creating AutoLayout constraints. It's very clean, and very simple.

See http://snapkit.io